# Adding external library into Qt Creator project

Tags: winapi, qt, qt-creator

Have created a simple library using vc6 compiler which defines a class Sum with a method add which takes two parameters and retruns an int, I have included this in my QT application in the pro file as

win32:LIBS +=D:\nest_qt_dev\SumLib\Debug\SumLib.lib

However I get an undefined reference to `CSum::Add(int, int)' error.

My Library Code Generation is Multi threaded Debug Dll.

Answer (score 1):

Remember to export the symbol in your library, then using it's header and lib file should work just fine;

http://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/sharedlibrary.html